# Should the hostname of my VPS point to the dedi IP of my Domain or to to a shared one used for new account creation?

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname

I leased a VPS which I want to use to sell shared hosting. 3 IPs - I call them A, B and C here for simplicity.
Actual setup is:
A=NS1.mydomain.com; host.mydomain.com and is used to set-up new accounts in shared environment
B=NS2.mydomain.com
C=dedicated IP for mydomain.com (SSL secured)
The more I read about DNS, the more I get confused; thus my question:
Is this configuration "Good Practice", especially the hostname pointing to A rather than to C?
And what would be a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a support specialist and got the following answer, which I would like to share:

> **The hostname should be always pointed to the main server IP
>   address.**
>
> **The main server IP address in the
>   server is "A".** You can verify it via
>   WHM >> Main >> Server Configuration >>
>   Basic cPanel & WHM Setup.
>
> The domain "mydomain.com" has SSL
>   installed in it. For installing the
>   SSL certificate you need to have a
>   dedicated IP Address. **Hence it is
>   pointed to the IP address "C".**
>
> **It is not necessary that the
>   main domain is pointed to the main
>   server IP address.**

Thus my above mentioned setup is logic and complies with 'Good Practice'